# Python3 Runserver TypeError {newbie}

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python, but I have looked all over for an answer to this problem. Seems like everybody is different though. I am on osx Mavericks, with Python 3.4 and Django 1.7.

When I run python3 manage.py runserver, I don't get any server details instead, I get

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute_from_command_line
Validating models...

utility.execute()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 408, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 244, in run_from_argv
0 errors found
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 291, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 76, in handle
self.run(*args, **options)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 85, in run
autoreload.main(self.inner_run, args, options)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 359, in main
reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 325, in python_reloader
reloader_thread()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 304, in reloader_thread
if fn():
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 173, in kqueue_code_changed
watcher = tempfile.TemporaryFile(bufsize=0)
TypeError: TemporaryFile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bufsize'
Exception ignored in: <bound method Signal._remove_receiver of  <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0x1022d1588>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 276, in _remove_receiver
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Python 3.4 is not yet supported for Django

Comment: Django 1.7 is still under heavy development; why are you using that version? Not that 1.7 supports Python 3.4 yet either.

Comment: I was initially using Python 2.7 but because I'm running Mavericks, I keep getting this error Segmentation fault: 11. I read on a different thread that Python3x fixes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're new to Python and Django, then use the most recent releases instead of the development versions. At the time of writing, the latest realeases are Django 1.6 and Python 2.7 or 3.3.

I would suggest using Python 2.7 with Django for now, since most of the tutorials and blogposts you find will be for Python 2.X.

Comment: 1.6 doesn't support Python 3.4, *at all*.

Comment: Nor does 1.7, for what it's worth.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I saw your warning in the comments above, and wanted to compliment that with advice to stick with the latest releases, and not just repeat what you had already said. I'm not familiar with the changelist for Python 3.4 -- is there anything that will require changes in Django?

Comment: Hi All, just wanted to say thanks for the help. I ended up deleting python3 completely, and reinstalled the previous version (3.3) and downgraded and uninstalled Django down to 1.5.